# Using Git to create an archive of added files

Tags: git

I am trying to create an archive with files that have been added to a specific subfolder between two commits.
To do this I run the following command in Git Bash:

```
git archive --format=zip --output=archive.zip $(git diff --diff-filter=A 16d80752 0cbb5afc -- Folder/SubFolder)
```

But it doesn't work. I see the following message: **Argument list too long**.

What could be my mistake?
I ran the following command:

```
git diff --diff-filter=A 16d80752 0cbb5afc  -- Folder/SubFolder
```

This command worked correctly.

Comment: How much lines? `git diff --diff-filter=A 16d80752 0cbb5af  -- Folder/SubFolder | wc -l` ???

Comment: There are 1303 lines..

Comment: Too much for a command line. Linux allows 16 kilobytes AFAIR. 1300 lines are surely much more.

Comment: It looks like I found the reason. The following command works correctly:
`git archive --format=zip --output=archive.zip HEAD $(git diff --diff-filter=A 16d80752 0cbb5afc --name-only Folder/SubFolder)`
I added `HEAD` and `--name-only`.